# Dual booting OpenSUSE and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I'd like to install OpenSUSE 13.2 on my computer alongside Ubuntu 14.10. All the guides I've found are outdated. I have 3 partitions on my disk: / (formatted as ext4), /home (ext4), and swap. Is dual booting possible? If so, how would I do it? I'm mainly concerned because 13.2 uses BTRFS as it's default file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. The SuSe installer will ask you how to partition your hard drive. At that point, you'll be able to choose to create a new partition using the empty space of one of your existing partitions. Then, you can choose to format that new partition as BTRFS or whatever else you like and install your new system there.

A safer approach might be to boot into a live session and create your partition manually before installing but, strictly speaking, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Would I mount it on the / partition?

Comment: @Terrance8D not sure what you mean. The **new** partition you create from the empty space available should be set as the `/` of the new system, yes. Whatever you do, do not use the `/` of the installed Ubuntu, that will overwrite your existing installation.

Comment: Glad I asked then. I'm pretty new to Linux, I've been using Ubuntu for about a month. I'm not entirely sure how it all works yet. Thanks for your help.:D